# Is the centralizer of a semisimple element in a connected algebraic group always connected

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

There is an exercise on page 142 of Humphreys' *Linear Algebraic Groups*:

> **Ex.1** Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group, $x \in G$ is semisimple. Must $C_G(x)$ be connected?

When $G$ is solvable, I think of another fact whose correctedness is proved on the book:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup (not necessarily closed) of a connected solvable group $G$, $H$ consisting of semisimple elements. Then $C_G(H) = N_G(H)$ is connected.

So, suppose that $G$ is solvable, set $H = \langle x \rangle$. It appears that $C_G(x)$ is connected.

I think the general case could be reduced to the solvable case if for any $y \in C_G(x)$, I can find a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing both $x$ and $y$. (Then $y$ must be in $C_B(x)$ which is connected.)

I think the Borel subgroup could be found, may be through the method of Borel variety. But I have difficulty in this.

Another exercise on the same page is:

> **Ex.2** Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group. If $x \in G$ has semisimple part $x_s$, then $x$ is contained in the identity component of $C_G(x_s)$.

If the answer to **Ex.1** is affirmative, then **Ex.2** would be obvious, since $x \in C_G(x_s)$. But I am not sure.

So, would you please tell me the answer to **Ex.1**, or help me with the proof or counterexample? If the centralizer could be not connected, how can I give **Ex.2** a proof?

Sincere thanks.

Comment: Dear ShinyaSakai, As a hint for Ex. 2, did you consider the case when $G = GL_n$?  Here the Jordan decomposition is very explicit, and you can see directly how to answer Ex. 2 (without having to think at all about Ex. 1).  Regards,

Comment: Also, regading Ex. 1, did you try any examples yourself?  It is always good to think about $SL_n$ and $GL_n$ first.  Also, since $SL_n$ is simply connected, it can be a little bit misleading sometimes, so it is good to think about $PGL_n$ too.  Regards,

Comment: Dear @Matt E: Thank you for the comments. **Ex.2** needs a proof, so do you mean the general case is done if it is proved in $GL_n$? For, **Ex.2**, I've thought of $GL_n$, in which semisimple elements can be considered as diagonal matrices. But it appears to me that the centralizer of a diagonal matrix in $GL_n$ is always connected. (For example, in $GL_3$, when $x$ is diagonal, with $1,2,1$ on the diagonal, has its centralizer isomorphic to $D_3 \times \mathbb{G}_a \times \mathbb{G}_a$, which is connected.) Is there any counterexample in $PGL_n$? Best regards,

Comment: Dear ShinyaSakai, Yes, it is true that centralizers of semisimple elements in $GL_n$ are connected, but why don't you try to prove Ex. 2 for $GL_n$ without using this fact, looking more directly at the Jordan decomposition.  The point is that then you may find an approach which you can generalize to other groups.  Regarding $PGL_n$, did you try looking for counterexamples?  Why don't you try $n = 2$ first, and think concretely about what it means to centralize an element in $PGL_2$, by working upstairs in $GL_2$?  Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The answer to Ex.1 is, in general, "no".
(It is "yes", in the case that $G$ is reductive and simply-connected).
For a counter-example, take $G=PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and
$$
x= \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array} \right].
$$
(Note, this is not a matrix, but the class of all its non-zero complex multiples, as $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})=GL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{C}^*$).

Then, you can check directly, by computation, that $C_G(x)$ is disconnected. There is also an interesting geometric way of identifying this centralizer. First note that $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the group of Möbius transformations acting transitively on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}P^1$. Since a matrix:
$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right] $$
corresponds to $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, the element $x$ above corresponds to the transformation $z\mapsto -z$, whose set of fixed points is $X=\{0,\infty\}$. The centralizer of $x$ can be viewed geometrically as the subgroup of Möbius transformations that sends $X$ to itself. These are the Möbius transformations of the form:
$$z\mapsto\alpha z, \, \mbox{ or }\, z\mapsto\frac{\alpha}{z}, $$
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$, which is clearly a disconnected group.

Comment: You mean that the centralizer of $\gamma$ is connected when $G$ is reductive, $G^\text{der}$ is simply connected, and $\gamma$ of semisimple.

Comment: Yes, that is probably a better statement, since it is more general. I believe that $G$ reductive and simply-connected, implies that $G$ is a semi-simple group, because of the exact sequence for a general reductive $G$, with derived subgroup $G^{der}$:
$$
1\to G^{der}\to G\to(\mathbb{C}^{*})^{d}\to1,
$$
where $d$ is the dimension of the center of $G$. Thus, $G$ being simply-connected implies $d=0$, and $G=G^{der}$. So, your condition is more general.

Comment: @Hexhist  May I ask one question? In the answer, you mentioned one can compute directly the centraliser to see it's not connected. I did the following: let $$c \in C_{G}(x), c =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2}\\
b_{1} & b_{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$ So $cx=xc$ gives $a_{2}=b_{1}=0$. I see $C_{G}(x)^{\circ}=T_{1}$. How to get the generators of $C/C^{\circ}$ from this computation? Thank you.

Comment: I'm awary that $C/C^{\circ}\cong Z_{2}$. Can we see it directly from the computation as I'm trying to generalize it to an arbitrary $n$ and an elementary abelian subgroup without involving roots, root subgroups, weyl groups, etc

Comment: @Hexhist It seems that the geometric argument only provides a necessary condition. For example, let $x=\begin{bmatrix} a & \\ & 1\end{bmatrix}$ with $a\neq \pm 1$. Then the set of fixed points of $x$ is still $\{ 0,\infty\}$, but this time the centralizer doesn't contain elements of the form $\begin{bmatrix} & \alpha \\ 1 & \end{bmatrix}$.